# React: Why is one of my prop variable undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-props, react-select

Hey I'm new to React and I'm having a problem with my prop which I'm passing to my ChildComponent. I am using "react-select" and have two multiselects. Originally I wanted to show in each select the value for the corresponding select I get from the state.

value={optionsColor.filter(item => ( myTest.color.includes(item.value)))}

But this is not possible because one of my calls is always "undefined". For example "myTest.Color" and "myTest.Car" one of them is "undefined" but I don't know why?
In my code (ChildComponent) I have two console.logs which illustrate this.

For example, if I select Color and have previously selected a car in Car, the console.log output looks like this.

undefined
blue

But I want it to output both.

```
    import {useState} from "react";
    import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
    
    const ParentComponent = () => {
        const [step, setStep] = useState(0)
    
        const [myTest, setMyTest] = useState(
            {
                color: ['defaultColor'],
                car: ['defaultCar'],
            }
        )
    
        const handleChange = (e, action) => {
            setMyTest({ [action.name]: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] })
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="card-body container mt-3">
                    <h2>Product data input Intended Use</h2>
                    <div className="card p-2 mt-5">
                        <form className="mb-4">
                            <div className="form"></div>
                            <ChildComponent myTest={myTest} handleChange={handleChange}/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    
    export default ParentComponent;
```

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import Select from 'react-select';
    
    const optionsColor = [
        { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue' },
        { value: 'red', label: 'Red' },
        { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow' }
    ]
    
    const optionsCar = [
        { value: 'bmw', label: 'BMW' },
        { value: 'ford', label: 'Ford' },
        { value: 'vw', label: 'VW' },
    ]
    
    const ChildComponent = ({ handleChange, myTest}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Car {console.log(myTest.car)}</h4>
                <Select
                    name="car"
                    options={optionsCar}
                    className="mb-3"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    //value={intendedUse.sex === undefined ? '' : optionsSex.filter(item => (intendedUse.sex.includes(item.value)))}
                    isMulti
                    autoFocus
                    isSearchable
                />
                <h4>Color {console.log(myTest.color)}</h4>
                <Select
                    name="color"
                    options={optionsColor}
                    className="mb-3"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    //value={intendedUse.age === undefined ? '': optionsAge.filter(item => ( intendedUse.age.includes(item.value)))}
                    isMulti
                    autoFocus
                    isSearchable
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: Don't console log in the render as an unintentional side-effect, the results are unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies here.

```
 setMyTest({ [action.name]: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] })
```

When you're updating your `myTest` state you're actually replacing both of the fields with the field you're setting.

Try something like this:

```
 setMyTest(myTest => ({...myTest, { [action.name]: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] }}));
```

In that way, you have a new object with both the field that changed and the one that didn't.

Comment: `setMyTest({...myTest, ...setMyTest({ [action.name]: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] } );` is that right? `...setMyTest({ [action.name]: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] } );` looks like you added in setMyTest call in there by mistake?

Comment: Yes, hasty error. My bad thanks @TomFinney

Comment: Missing a closing curly bracket. Also, whenever you are spreading in state like this be sure to use a functional state update so you are updating from the previous state versus whatever state is closed over in the callback, i.e. `setMyTest(myTest => ({ ...myTest, [action.name]: e ? e.map(x => x.value) : [] }));`, note that you don't need to spread the key-value you are updating.

Comment: updating the post indeed you're correct @DrewReese thanks :)